# Replace xBD character to blank value

Tags: regex, powershell

In powershell, how to replace XBD character to blank space from the text file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `xBD` refers to the underlying ASCII value, `0xBD`, it should be as easy as:

```
$string.Replace("$(0xBD -as [char])","")
```

---

For multiple lines (eg. an entire text file), use the `-replace` regex operator.

The syntax for the `-replace` operator is:

```
"string(s)" -replace "regex pattern","replacement"
```

If you omit the "replacement" argument, the characters matched by the regex pattern will simply be removed.

The proper regex pattern in .NET to match that character would be `\xBD`:

```
(Get-Content .\myfile.txt) -replace '\xBD' | Set-Content .\mynewfile.txt
```

Comment: What wrong of this command ? $FinalOutput = Get-Content -path 'D:\PowerShell\BD_char.txt'
$FinalOutput -Replace("$(0xBD -as [char])","") Set-Content 'D:\PowerShell\BD_char_Output.txt'

Comment: Solved when I put | between ) and set-content. TQ

Comment: @user664481 Updated answer with a full example using `-replace` and a proper regex pattern

Comment: Question how to modify command so it will replace xBD and xB5 to blank value ? or a regx command that can replace any underlying ASCII value like xBD,xB5 and etc to a blank value

Comment: You can speficy multiple characters in your pattern like so: `[\xB5\xBD]`